# Изменение содержимого сообщений подтверждения почты ( Django Rest Framework, Djoser )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Вопрос краток, не требует отрывков кода, а заголовок вопроса и так описывает суть моей проблемы, но зная любовь товарещей модеров удалять мои вопросы, я уточню:

Я использую Djoser для аутентификации на своем DRF проекте, так-же использую подтверждение адреса email при аутентификации, но мне не нравится содержимое отправляемого сообщения, и я хотел бы узнать где это можно было-бы указать явно, с учетом того, что нужно использовать значения uid/token ?

Comment: Если возникнут вопросы - пишите их под ответом, чтобы мне пришли уведомления. Если все ок и ответ помог вам, то можете поставить галочку слева от ответа. См. справку [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Djoser имеется конфигурация, которая отвечает за шаблоны email:

```
    "EMAIL": ObjDict(
        {
            "activation": "djoser.email.ActivationEmail",
            "confirmation": "djoser.email.ConfirmationEmail",
            "password_reset": "djoser.email.PasswordResetEmail",
            "password_changed_confirmation": "djoser.email.PasswordChangedConfirmationEmail",
            "username_changed_confirmation": "djoser.email.UsernameChangedConfirmationEmail",
            "username_reset": "djoser.email.UsernameResetEmail",
        }
    ),
```

В которой указаны классы, описывающие шаблоны писем.
В каждом классе указаны файлы HTML с содержимым шаблона
https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/conf.py#L66

```
class ActivationEmail(BaseEmailMessage):
    template_name = "email/activation.html"
```

Вот ссылка на встроенный шаблон подтверждения:
https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/templates/email/activation.html

#### Что нужно делать?

Вам необходимо переопределить класс `ActivationEmail` где вы сможете указать свой путь до шаблона.

```
from djoser import email

class ActivationEmail(email.ActivationEmail):
    template_name = 'email/activation.html'
```

После чего в настройках(**settings.py**) вы должны указать какой класс, описывает данный шаблон.
*(в данном случае предполагается, что этот класс находится в `core/email.py`)*

```
DJOSER = {
    'EMAIL': {
            'activation': 'core.email.ActivationEmail'
    }
}
```

#### Способ №2

Я думаю также может быть способ попроще, в котором Вы просто можете переопределить перевод тех или иных токенов в шаблоне

Comment: Сделал все действия, но есть небольшая проблема, в том что он пытается найти template в файлах Djoser`a , * При этом, сам путь к template он взял с собственно прописанного мною класса *, как мне ему ткнуть мордой в папку проекта для поиска template ?

Comment: @ACC, а по какому пути вы расположили свои шаблоны?

Comment: @ACC по идее нужно в `templates/djoser/email/activation.html` если ничего не путаю.

Comment: Все наладил, спасибо

Comment: @ACC отлично! спасибо, что написали, а то я пошел уже разворачивать приложение новое для проверки

Comment: Вам спасибо за помощь